# AWS ssh login by ubuntu ternminal not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have set amazon instance. I configured the proxy correctly.
I am getting this error.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host.

Here is my .ssh/config file

```
Host AWS
Hostname 52.76.70.56
Port 22
User ubuntu
IdentityFile Desktop/aws1/tutorial.pem
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew 10.3.100.207 8080  %h %p
```

Comment: Have you opened up port 22 in the instance's security group in EC2?

Comment: yes I did, I set the proxy correctly. Now I am getting the error ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: Try adding -v to your ssh command. This will show what keys are being tried and at what point in the process the connection is being closed. Post the results here if like and I/we can diagnose them.

Comment: Also, is the tutorial.pem file the private key that's assigned to the proxy?

Comment: yes tutorial.pem is the private key

Comment: Here is the verbose output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87693/discussion-between-user3651854-and-seren).

Answer (score 0):

As seen image, you had used two ssh command and no need to mention key-pair file name using double quote.

Use single ssh command

```
ssh -i <my-key-pair.pem> <user>@<ip-address>
```

Check the key-pair has necessary permissions, you can use following command to set permission

```
chmod 400 <my-key-pair.pem>
```

And the user will be your instance user name, in case of ec2-instance the user name may be **ec2-user** and for ubuntu instance the user name is **ubuntu**

Thanks